how reentrant locks ensures mutual exclusion?
I am confused about the reentrant lock and mutual exclusion if a thread can reacquire lock multiple times doesn't it violet mutual exclusion because other thread also wants to acquire the lock?
i know that reentrant locks are used for recursive function so that it doesn't enter deadlock when doing recursion but how does it ensures mutual exclusion?

Are you excluding yourself from your house when you lock your door and then throw the deadbolt too?  From inside the house?

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of "mutual exclusion". It means that two different threads can't simultaneously hold the lock. That's still true of a reentrant lock.

This is implemented by having the system keep track of which thread holds the lock. When attempting to lock it, if it's held by a different thread, then the attempt returns failure or blocks. If it's held by the same thread, it simply increments an internal counter and returns success.

The answer to your question depends upon the nature of the operating system.  In an interrupt driven operating system (ie supports software interrupts) allowing the same thread to acquire a reentrant lock does not guarentee mutual exclusion. If threads execute exclusively sequentially then it does have mutual exclusion.
In the former case:
Main thread code Locks Resource
Main thread code starts to manipulate Resource.
Thread interrupt executes
Thread interrupt locks Resource.
Thread Interrupt manipulates resource
thread Interrupt unlock resource
Main thread code finishes manipulting Resource
Main thread code unlocks Resource
Resource is in an indeterminant state.
